# Reinstall template

Tags: templates, joomla-4.x, css, cassiopeia

I have an installed template on the site all ready, but I want to reinstall it without removing any content. From my understanding you can just remove the entry from the database?

How do I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the Template from the data base you need to use an editor such as phpMyAdmin that is normally accessible via your hosting control panel, eg cPanel.

The table you are looking for is `<prefix>_extensions` and then you can scroll or search through the table to remove the single line for your template.

[image]

Any settings saved within the parameters for the template will also be removed therefore you may want to copy and paste them somewhere safe and paste them back once you have reinstalled the template.

[image]

By '...without removing any content' I am assuming you are to referring the files and customisations/overrides in the /template folder.

Comment: Yes Thank you. Great answer and explanation ^^ 

I normally reinstall my custom component this way. Ive learnt the hardships of uninstalling instead of removing from db.